# Microsoft Exchange 2010 Unified Messaging installation

Tags: exchange-2010, prerequisites

where i can find

The Unified Messaging role in Exchange 2010 has the following prerequisites:

```
Unified Communications Managed API 2.0
Microsoft Speech Platform Server Runtime 10.1
```

as i can't install Unified messaging and i have tried UCMA runtime 3.0

and all links for download are expired or doesn't exist in other websites, and if there is any work around and what i should install or enable

Thank you

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to install this?

Comment: my company decided to get back to use MS exchange on premises, and we used to use MS exchange 2010, and it was uninstalled long time ago and now they need the mailboxes as we have the data backed up, so i want to install it then move the mail boxes to the new Exchange, and i have tried UCMA 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 ,6.0 ... and i still can't install the unified messaged role to be installed

Comment: Why aren't you installing a supported version of Exchange?

Comment: because i have tried and mailboxes didn't be transferred the right way and as it was backed up from MS exchange 2010, that why i want that UCMA so i can install MS Exchange 2010 then move the mail boxes to a higher Exchange

Comment: so unless UCMA runtime 2.0 is available or there is another work around

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Comment: Build a new server with a supported version of Exchange Server. Create your user mailboxes. Use a third party utility to export the contents of the old mailboxes from the mailbox database of the old server and import them into the new mailboxes on the new server.

Comment: Thank You Joe ... much appreciated

Comment: To install Exchange on a Windows Server, you need both the Exchange version and Windows Server version to be high enough and compatible to each other, as documented in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/supportability-matrix In your case, Exchange 2010 is end of life, and it was only supported on Windows Server 2012 which is going to reach end of life in just a few months. Thus, all related downloads have already been removed from Microsoft download site and you cannot turn back the time. If you really want an on premise Exchange installation, use recent versions.

Comment: Any update on this thread?

Comment: Thank you Aaron ... my problem is to transfer the Unified messaging role to the new Exchange ... that's why i been searching for Unified Communications Manager API 2.0, so i can replicate it or move it to new Exchange ... Unified Messaging Role requires UCMA 2.0 so it can be installed, i can move the mailboxes, public folders and OAB ... just this what I can't for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=976657

I'm not sure if this link is correct. I haven't downloaded it yet.

Comment: Thank you ... I have already tried that https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Unified%20communications%20Manager%20API%202.0

Comment: Anyway, i'm glad to hear that issue has been solved, Please do not forget mark helpful reply as an answer. Thansk! : )

Comment: Any update on this thread? If you mark a helpful reply as an answer, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well.